# For Visual Studio Community 2015 can I use code coverage functionality for C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, vs-community-edition

I am using MVS Community 2015 for C++. I have also used Unit Testing framework of Microsoft and that is just amazing. The problem is that I don't have data about coverage. Can I analyze the coverage for C++ while running all unit tests?

For the solution that has a project for unit testing I see that there is something like this:[image]

But when I try to execute it seems that it should work only on managed code:

```
Project: LessUnitTest
Configuration: Debug
Scope: None
Assembly: .....\Less\Debug\LessUnitTest.dll
Maintainability Index: 
Cyclomatic Complexity: 
Depth of Inheritance: 
Class Coupling: 
Lines of Code: 
Message: The project target file '.....\Less\Debug\LessUnitTest.dll' contains no managed code.
```

Any thoughts?

EDIT: I have seen [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jsocha/2011/08/16/capturing-c-code-coverage-with-visual-c/) that didn't help me to find steps how to check the coverage. But looks someone could do that. :(

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Enterprise is the *only* VS edition that has Code Coverage feature

https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/ (Testing Tools - Code Coverage)